# Android - Show on-screen keyboard while a hardware keyboard is connected

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a peripheral device which is basically a keyboard (with incomplete buttons)
connected via a mini-USB cord to a tablet. I am setting focus to a TextField for input.

I have used both Libgdx functions

```
Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true);
```

and native Android/Java functions

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) appActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(appActivity.getCurrentFocus(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

They both work while the hardware keyboard is disconnected 
but don't when the hardware is connected.

Is there a way to tell Android/Libgdx to disable hardware keyboard?